# Asp.net pulling data from a dataset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

A little background. This is my first asp.net project written in VB, i have very little knowledge of programming other than a little sql.

So to my issue. I'm building a site that on button click it will search based on OrderNumer and pull the order information and populate a few txt boxes with the data. I created a dataset with the data i need. Now if i change it to look at my sql table I have no errors yet no data is pulled, but if i try to use my dataset i get an invalid object error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim SqlQuery As String
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection

    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Myserver;database=XXXXX;uid=XXXXX;password=XXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;"

    SqlQuery = ("SELECT ShipName + ShipName2 FROM ds Where OrderNumber =" & txtOrderNumber.Text & " ")
    conn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = SqlQuery

    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If sdr.HasRows Then
        While sdr.Read()
            txtFullName.Text = sdr.Item("ShipName").ToString
        End While
        sdr.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("OrderNumber #" & txtOrderNumber.Text & " " & "Not Found.")

    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line of code are you recieving that error?

Comment: I don't think the result set from your SQL query will contain a ShipName column as your SQL appends the ShipName and ShipName2 columns. Try changing your select to 'SELECT ShipName + ShipName2 AS ShipName ...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SqlQuery assignment should look more like this:

```
SqlQuery = ("SELECT ShipName + ShipName2 FROM ds Where OrderNumber ='" & txtOrderNumber.Text & "' ")
```

Notice the only change is to surround the txtOrderNumber.Text value with single quotes.

By the way this type of code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You should use SQL parameters.

Comment: This depends on what the content of the text box is. If it's a number the syntax is fine. Correct on the SQL injection though, parameters are the way to go.

Comment: Agreed Calvedos, but based on the error I can assume that OrderNumber is either not a number or the column type for OrderNumber is of the text variety.